# How to join multiple arrays in ruby which has equal size

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, iteration

I have the following code:

```
prices  = [["12.34", "23.12"], ["12.22", "66.11", "33.66", "11.11"], ["32.12"]]
names   = [["dog", "pog"], ["foo", "bar", "baz", "zed"], ["qwerty"]]
numbers = [["2", "3"], ["12", "33", "444", "3023"], ["33393"]]
pics    = [["url", "url"], ["url", "url", "url", "url"], ["url"]]
chars   = ["A", "B", "C"]
```

How to join arrays, that the result array will be:

```
[["12.34", "dog", "2", "url", "A"], ["23.12", "pog", "3", "url", "A"],
 ["12.22", "foo", "12", "url", "B"], ["66.11", "bar", "33", "url", "B"],
 ...
 ["32.12", "qwerty", "33393", "url", "C"]]
```

I tryed join arrays through zip method, but result was:

```
[[["12.34", "23.12"], ["dog", "pog"], ["2", "3"], ["url", "url"], ["A", "B", "C"]]]
...
```

Comment: Please attach some sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
chars.map.with_index {|char, i| 
  prices[i].zip(names[i], numbers[i], pics[i], [char].cycle)
}.flatten(1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it produced: [["12.34", "dog", "2", "url", ["A", "B", "C"], "23.12", "pog", "3", "url", ["A", "B", "C"]]]

Comment: No way. Although this solution is a bit stodgy in my humble opinion, it’s perfectly correct.

Comment: yes, my fail (extra braces in  chars array) , sorry. Thank you Jörg W Mittag&&mudasobwa

Comment: Honestly, I wonder why you picked up this one solution, but it’s definitely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [ 
  [["12.34", "23.12"], ["12.22", "66.11", "33.66", "11.11"], ["32.12"]],
  [["dog", "pog"], ["foo", "bar", "baz", "zed"], ["qwerty"]],
  [["2", "3"], ["12", "33", "444", "3023"], ["33393"]],
  [["url", "url"], ["url", "url", "url", "url"], ["url"]],
  ["A", "B", "C"]
] # == [prices,names,numbers,pics,chars]

arr.transpose.map do |e|
  e[0...-1].reduce(:zip).map { |r| r.flatten << e.last }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
e = chars.cycle
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["A", "B", "C"]:cycle> 
[prices, names, numbers, pics].map(&:flatten).transpose.map { |arr| arr << e.next }
  #=> [["12.34", "dog",        "2", "url", "A"],
  #    ["23.12", "pog",        "3", "url", "B"],
  #    ["12.22", "foo",       "12", "url", "C"],
  #    ["66.11", "bar",       "33", "url", "A"],
  #    ["33.66", "baz",      "444", "url", "B"],
  #    ["11.11", "zed",     "3023", "url", "C"],
  #    ["32.12", "qwerty", "33393", "url", "A"]]
```

The steps:

```
a = [prices, names, numbers, pics].map(&:flatten)
  #=> [["12.34", "23.12",..."32.12"],
  #    ["dog", "pog",..."qwerty"],
  #    ["2", "3",..."33393"],
  #    ["url",...,"url"]] 
b = a.transpose
  #=> [["12.34", "dog", "2", "url"],
  #    ["23.12", "pog", "3", "url"],
  #    ...
  #    ["32.12", "qwerty", "33393", "url"]] 
b.map { |arr| arr << e.next }
  #=> the above result
```